# Repaint() relocating buttons

Tags: java, swing

I'm writing a Java program that will draw a circle or rectangle depending on the button pressed. While it does draw the given shape, upon drawing it creates new buttons at the top left((0,0) most likely) of the window. Am I breaking some rule of paint()/repaint()?

Here's my class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class Components extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
  String em="Nothing";
  public Components()
{
    JButton c=new JButton("Rectangle");
    JButton b=new JButton("Circle");
    b.addActionListener(this);
    c.addActionListener(this);
    add(c, 0);
    add(b, 1);
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    setVisible(true);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Rectangle"))
    {
        em="Rectangle";
        repaint();
    }
    else
    {
        em="Circle";
        repaint();
    }
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    if(em.equals("Rectangle"))
    {
        g.drawRect(50, 50, 50, 50);
    }
    else if(em.equals("Circle"))
    {
        g.drawOval(50, 50, 50, 50);
    }

}

}
```

As well as the less-important JFrame class:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class Wndw extends JFrame
{
    public Wndw()
    {
        setTitle("Hello");
        setSize(400, 400);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(new Components());
    }

public static void main (String [] args)
{
    new Wndw();
}
}
```

Comment: for clarification can i ask why you're not using some form of layout manager? the motivation behind this would be to have your buttons and paintings reside in their respective layout. this way when repaint is called, it calls it only on that particular layout section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's got (very little) to do with `repaint` and everything to do with your violation of the painting routines

Start by having a look at [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details into how painting works.

`paint` delegates it's responsibilities, by calling `paintComponent`, `paintBorder` and `paintChildren`.  When you override `paint` and fail to call it's `super` method, you are breaking this responsibility and you end up with issues like you have now.

The `Graphics` context is a shared resource among Swing components.  Every component which is painted during a paint cycle gets the same `Graphics`. This means, one of the first things that should be done, is the `Graphics` context should be prepared for the component to paint on it.  This is typically done by the `paintComponent` method, which you are no longer calling

The first thing to do to is, stop overriding `paint` and instead, which is generally recommended, override `paintComponent`, it limits your overall responsibility and reduces the risk of introducing further issues.

Next, call `super.paintComponent` before you do any custom painting...

```
public class Components extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    //....
    @Overrride
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if(em.equals("Rectangle"))
        {
            g.drawRect(50, 50, 50, 50);
        }
        else if(em.equals("Circle"))
        {
            g.drawOval(50, 50, 50, 50);
        }    
    }
```

> But when I do this, what was previously paint is erased

Yes, that's how painting works.  It's destructive.  When ever a paint pass is executed, you are expected to repaint the entire state of the component as it is at that point in time.

If you wish to preserve what was previously painted, you have two basic choices.

1. Draw everything to a backing buffer (image) and paint that
2. Store the "commands" you need to redraw the context from scratch in some kind of `List`

There are plenty of examples of both